# Process items of array for a ListView DataTemplate in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, uwp

I have the following DataTemplate which I use for a custom ListView layout in my UWP app:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:contract7Present="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 7)"
    xmlns:utils="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Utils"
    x:Class="ClassevivaPCTO.Controls.DataTemplates.AgendaEventListViewDataTemplate"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">

    <utils:AgendaEvent x:Key="AgendaEvent"/>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="AgendaEventListViewDataTemplate"
                  
                  x:DataType="utils:AgendaEvent">
        <RelativePanel>
    

                <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           MaxWidth="500"
                                           Text="{x:Bind subjectDesc}"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="12,6,0,0" />

            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="eventTitle" x:Name="eventType" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           MaxWidth="500"
                                           Text="{x:Bind evtCode}"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="12,6,0,0" />


        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Text value of the TextBlock items is bound to a custom data type class called AgendaEvent:

```
    public class AgendaEvent
    {
        public int evtId { get; set; }
        public string evtCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime evtDatetimeBegin { get; set; }
        public DateTime evtDatetimeEnd { get; set; }
        public bool isFullDay { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
        public string authorName { get; set; }
        public string classDesc { get; set; }
        public object subjectId { get; set; }
        public object subjectDesc { get; set; }
        public object homeworkId { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewAgendaEvents"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AgendaEventListViewDataTemplate}"                   
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
</ListView>
```

And from an array of `AgendaEvent` objects that I get from a custom array factory I set the `ItemsSource` to the ListView:

```
ListViewAgendaEvents.ItemsSource = customArray.AgendaEvents;
```

---

I realized that for my needs the `eventTitle` TextBlock needs to have the properties `authorName` and `subjectDesc` combined together as a string with custom decoration characters. For example: `authorName + " - wrote: " + subjectDesc`.

Not always the `subjectDesc` is available, so I need to dinamically adjust the `eventTitle` textblock with various conditionals checks.

I thought about using an adapter class just like for Android's listviews but with UWP's data binding it is very confusing how to accomplish what I want to do.

Is there a simple and straightforward way to combine properties in a custom string and execute checks before displaying properties for a DataTemplate used in a ListView in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Roy Li's answer, I used the following method that most suits my needs and resembles in part Android's adapters architecture:

This is a separate class that acts as an "adapter" or "view model" for the xaml listview item. In the constructor it takes the original object type with the properties I want to process:

```
public class AgendaEventAdapter
{
    public AgendaEvent CurrentObject;

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentObject.subjectDesc))
            {
                return CurrentObject.authorName;
            }
            else
            {
                return CurrentObject.subjectDesc + " (" + CurrentObject.authorName + ")";
            }
        }
    }

    public string EventType
    {
        get
        {

            return "[" + CurrentObject.evtCode + "]";
        }
    }

    public string Notes => CurrentObject.notes;

    public AgendaEventAdapter(AgendaEvent ev)
    {
        CurrentObject = ev;
    }
}
```

This is the DataTemplate used in the listview (note that the DataType is now the adapter class `AgendaEventAdapter`):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:contract7Present="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 7)"
    xmlns:converters="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Converters"
    xmlns:utils="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Utils"
    xmlns:adapters="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Adapters"
    x:Class="ClassevivaPCTO.Controls.DataTemplates.AgendaEventListViewDataTemplate"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">

    <converters:DateTimeToHourConverter x:Key="DateTimeToHourConverter" />


    <DataTemplate x:Key="AgendaEventListViewDataTemplate"
                  
                  x:DataType="adapters:AgendaEventAdapter">
        <RelativePanel>
    

                <TextBlock x:Name="titoloEvento" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           MaxWidth="500"
                                           Text="{x:Bind Title}"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="6,6,0,0" />

            
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="titoloEvento" x:Name="tipoEvento" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           MaxWidth="500"
                                           Text="{x:Bind EventType}"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="6,6,0,0" />


            <TextBlock RelativePanel.Below="titoloEvento" x:Name="dataStart"
                                           Text="{x:Bind  CurrentObject.evtDatetimeBegin, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToHourConverter}}"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="6,0,0,0" />

            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="dataStart" RelativePanel.Below="titoloEvento" x:Name="placeholderData"
                                           Text="-"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="6,0,6,0" />


            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="placeholderData" RelativePanel.Below="titoloEvento" x:Name="dataEnd"
                                           Text="{x:Bind  CurrentObject.evtDatetimeEnd, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToHourConverter}}"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0" />

            <TextBlock RelativePanel.Below="dataStart" x:Name="descriptionEvent"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="{x:Bind  CurrentObject.notes}"
                                           Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                           Margin="6,6,0,6" />
            
            



        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And this is the code to create an instance of the adapter class for every item which then are passed to the listview's `ItemsSource` property:

```
// Wrap each AgendaEvent object in an instance of AgendaEventAdapter and handle null case
var eventAdapters = overviewResult.AgendaEvents
    ?.Select(evt => new AgendaEventAdapter(evt))
    .ToList();

ListViewAgendaDate.ItemsSource = eventAdapters;
```

This is the best solution to my problem as having a separate model class can be helpful to reduce clutter in the code and also can be useful in case of usage of observable objects that bind with the item's views.

Answer (score 1):

**Update3**

UWP doesn't support multiple data binding, it only accepts single value. If you don't want to change the Xaml binding, then please try to do it in the DataModel. Create a new message string in the AgendaEvent Class and do the checks will be the simplest way.

```
 public class AgendaEvent
{
    public int evtId { get; set; }
    public string evtCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime evtDatetimeBegin { get; set; }
    public DateTime evtDatetimeEnd { get; set; }
    public bool isFullDay { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string authorName { get; set; }
    public string classDesc { get; set; }
    public object subjectId { get; set; }
    public object subjectDesc { get; set; }
    public object homeworkId { get; set; }

    public string messageString
    {
        get
        {
            if (subjectDesc == null)
            {
                return authorName;
            }
            return authorName + " - wrote: " + subjectDesc;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Text="{x:Bind messageString}"
                                       Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0" />
```

**Update2:**

I come up with another way which should also be able to achieve what you want. It requires different templates. You just need to choose different `DataTemplate` based on the values using [DataTemplateSelector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector?view=winrt-22621)

Code-behind:

```
 public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Normal { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Unusual { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        AgendaEvent agendaEvent = (AgendaEvent)item;
        // if you have other reuqirements, just need to add more check and different templates
        if (agendaEvent.subjectDesc != null)
        {
            return Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            return Unusual;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
   <Page.Resources>
     <!--tempalte for normal value-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:AgendaEvent">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0">
                            <Run Text="{x:Bind authorName}"/>
                            <Run Text=" - wrote: "/>
                            <Run Text="{x:Bind subjectDesc}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="eventTitle" x:Name="eventType" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Text="{x:Bind evtCode}"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0" />

        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>
     <!--template for null value-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UnusualItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:AgendaEvent">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0">
                            <Run Text="{x:Bind authorName}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="eventTitle" x:Name="eventType" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Text="{x:Bind evtCode}"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0" />

        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector" 
                                  Normal="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}"
                                  Unusual="{StaticResource UnusualItemTemplate}"/>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewAgendaEvents"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
       
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**Update:**

You could try to create a custom [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-22621) to do the job. You could check the binding value in the Converter event and customize the output binding string.

Code-behind:

```
  public class TextBlockValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else 
        {
            return " - wrote: " + value.ToString();
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <local:TextBlockValueConverter x:Key="TextBlockValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

   <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0">
                          <Run Text="{x:Bind authorName}"/>
                          <Run Text="{x:Bind subjectDesc, Converter={StaticResource TextBlockValueConverter} }"/>
                    </TextBlock>
```

**Old**

> Is there a simple and straightforward way to combine properties in a custom string for a DataTemplate used in a ListView in UWP?

Since you are using a `TextBlock`, then the solution will be very simple. You just need to use `Run` inside a `TextBlock`. And bind the text you want to different `Run`.

You just need to change the code like this:

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="eventTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxWidth="500"
                                       Margin="12,6,0,0">
                          <Run Text="{x:Bind authorName}"/>
                          <Run Text=" - wrote: "/>
                          <Run Text="{x:Bind subjectDesc}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. But how can I apply checks to the properties before displaying them? I updated my question so that the request is clear

Comment: @Gabboxl I'm a little confused. The update is not very clear. Can you be more specific about the final behavior you want to get? Which property needs to be checked and what's the check logic?

Comment: In my case I want to check whether the value `subjectDesc` is null before displaying a custom string value in the `eventTitle` textblock. If the `subjectDesc` is null then only the `authorName` I want to be displayed, otherwise `subjectDesc` and `authorName` properties should be combined in a single string via the `" - wrote: "` string, like you did in your answer.

Comment: @Gabboxl I've updated my answer. You could use `ValueConverter` to achieve this. Please refer to the code example in my code.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is this method really the only way to achieve this? I would need to rewrite all my templates for every property I want to check and dynamically adjust this way. Is there a way to mimic Android's custom Adapter class method instead?

Comment: @Gabboxl Just based on the question, this is the only way.

Comment: @Gabboxl I just come up with another way. You could use the `DataTemplateSelector Class` to select different template for different value of the data. Please check update2

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but I don't think following this way suits my needs at best: I plan to have lots of DataTemplates and by following this way I would need to write many redundant similar DataTemplates and Dataselectors to accomplish what I want to do, and this is unsustainable. I am in search of a more unified way to manage the values displayed in DataTemplates, something like Android's Adapters methodology.

Comment: @Gabboxl UWP doesn't support multiple data binding, it only accepts single value. If you don't want to change the Xaml binding, then please try to do it in the DataModel. Create a new message string in the AgendaEvent Class and do the checks will be the simplest way. I've updated my answer for a simple example.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the update, I've been using this last solution (but placing the custom properties in a separate custom class) for a few days and I feel this is the best solution so far which comes close to what I wanted to do. I didn't expect achieving something that simple would be so unintuitive in UWP. I added the code I used in a separate answer.